# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/cms/Recipient

Tags: java, itext, bouncycastle

```
public class PDFEncryption {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException, IOException{
        
        String inputfile = "C:\\CC_Storage\\Workspaces\\PDFEncryption\\input\\statement_20171118.pdf";
        String outputfile = "C:\\CC_Storage\\Workspaces\\PDFEncryption\\output\\statement_20171118.pdf";
        
        PdfEncryptor.encrypt(
                new PdfReader(inputfile),
                new FileOutputStream(outputfile),
                null,
                "StrongPassword".getBytes(),
                PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS);
        
    }
}
```

I am trying to encrypt the pdf by using above code but getting below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/cms/Recipient
    at PDFEncryption.main(PDFEncryption.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.cms.Recipient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more
```

Can someone please help me what to do?

Comment: Which BouncyCastle version do you have in your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Dependent external library jar was missing while compiling your code,
If you are compiling with commandline, then use the below commands to compile and run

```
javac -cp ".:./ext.jar" PDFEncryption.java 
java -cp ".:./ext.jar" PDFEncryption
```

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/example.html)

If you are using Eclipse IDE, You can add a jar by right-clicking on the Project → Build Path → Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and give the Jar.

Comment: jagadesh, how i'll know which version of bouncy castle jar i have to use?

Comment: @AmanGupta,Version you need to select based on your work requirement. You can check the available versions https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=bouncycastle